# JPanel ActionMethod when it is shown

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel

I search for a method, which gets called if the jpanel is shown on the display, because i have to fetch the real size of the panel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to the JPanel? That would be where I would start with my code in the `componentShown(...)` method. For this to work, I think that you must call `setVisible(true)` on the JPanel after adding it to the display.

The other option is to simply query its size after calling `pack()`, or `setVisible(true)` on  your GUI.

**Edit**
You state:

> I added the panel to the gui designer.. when the window pops up, i wanna now the real size of the jpanel, because it can change it.

If you want to know the size of a component held by a window "when the window pops up", then add a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to the window and check the size of the component from the `windowOpened(...)` method.

**Edit 2**
Then you state:

> after i have the real size, i add some subpanels, in relation to the size of this panel. so e.g. size/6 & the subpanel has now the size-height of size/6.

One Solution: Better not to set the sizes of anything but instead to use the right combination of layout managers and then let them set the proper sizes based on their rules.

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler: what is the actual issue? Are you adding the JPanel after the GUI is up and running, or are you adding it to the GUI prior to displaying the GUI and you simply want to test its size after rendering the GUI? Also, what are you going to do with this information once you have it?

Comment: I added the panel to the gui designer.. when the window pops up, i wanna now the real size of the jpanel, because it can change it.

Comment: after i have the real size, i add some subpanels, in relation to the size of this panel. so e.g. size/6 & the subpanel has now the size-height of size/6.

Comment: that's the problem,.. because I have one JFrame.. in this JFrame there is a mainpanel.. and i can switch between more views (panels) so, I wanna have the size when this view(panel) came up.. so the windowlistener is not useful here. but i wonder, why the componentShown method doesn't work...!?

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler: componentShown only works when you call `setVisible(true)` on the component. Can you show any images of your problem -- what your current GUI looks like, and what you're trying to get it to look like? I still think that smart use of layout managers may work well for you.

Comment: yeah i'm on to change it with layouts - and works fine ;) thanks a lot!

Comment: arrgghh ... how comes that myths die so hard ;-) A ComponentListener's componentShown is _rarely ever_ useful as it fires only if the visible property _changes_ (which it doesn't because its default is true). So again, for the umptieth time: the intuitive "visibility" notification happens via an AncestorListener.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility using function setVisible(true);

Comment: looks like you didn't understand the quesstion :-)